# ios8: input accessory view crashed

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uitextview, first-responder, xcode6.1

I have an `UITextView` which have an accessory view.

**Crashed Code:**

```
textView.inputAccessoryView = _myView;   // Code written in ViewDidLoad of my Controller
[textView becomeFirstResponder];    // <- Crash Point   - Code called on button click
```

It had run perfectly before I updated my device to **IOS 8.1**. Now app crashes on the line

```
[textView becomeFirstResponder];
```

**No Crash:**

But if I comment the code like this, app does not crash.

```
//textView.inputAccessoryView = _myView;
[textView becomeFirstResponder];
```

I even tried to set the `accessory View` of `textView` to `nil` and then added mine but still app crashes. Although I have seen many questions where people have been able to successfuly add their `accessory view` to `textView`. I just can't figure out my issue.
I want to know the reason and solution for this.
Kindly look into this.

Comment: I tried to add accessoryView and it's working fine. I added it all on viewDidLoad. Can you tell what is inside _myView and where does this becomeFirstResponder being called? And also the most important, what is the error message?

Comment: _myView is a view which contains many buttons intended for rich text editing. I want to add myView as inputaccessory view to my text view. Scene is When I click a button called take note new view opens up which has my textView. On take note button click this line [textView becomeFirstResponder] is called. Here app crashes.